# Sharepoint2013:Getting error onclick of selectedShapeText Button which is provided by new javascript api for Visio provided by microsoft

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, visio

I am working on visio in SharePoint-2013 using visio web access web part .In VWA  I was able to read all the shapes and there by displaying shape text. Now Microsoft has released new javascript api . where it will take the url of the visio file and it displays Visio on click of a button named initEmbeddedframe.

Also they have given one more button, on click of which selected shape text is supposed to display.But it's coming to catch block of getSelectedShapeText() method. As I am new to sharepoint as well as Visio I need help from you guys.

would like to provide the code which need to be embed in Script editor web aprt of a sharepoint page.

```js
<script src='https://visioonlineapi.azurewebsites.net/visio.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

Enter Visio File Url:<br/>
<script language="javascript">
document.write("<input type='text' id='fileUrl' size='120'/>");
document.write("<input type='button' value='InitEmbeddedFrame' onclick='initEmbeddedFrame()' />");
document.write("<br />");
document.write("<input type='button' value='SelectedShapeText' onclick='getSelectedShapeText()' />");
document.write("<textarea id='ResultOutput' style='width:350px;height:60px'> </textarea>");
document.write("<div id='iframeHost' />");

var textArea;
// Loads the Visio application and Initializes communication between devloper frame and Visio online frame
function initEmbeddedFrame() {
        textArea = document.getElementById('ResultOutput');
 var url = document.getElementById('fileUrl').value;
 if (!url) {
     window.alert("File URL should not be empty");
 }
 // APIs are enabled for EmbedView action only.   
 url = url.replace("action=view","action=embedview");
 url = url.replace("action=interactivepreview","action=embedview");
  
       var session = new OfficeExtension.EmbeddedSession(url, { id: "embed-iframe",container: document.getElementById("iframeHost") });
       return session.init().then(function () {
     // Initilization is successful 
     textArea.value  = "Initilization is successful";
     OfficeExtension.ClientRequestContext._overrideSession = session;
 });
     }

// Code for getting selected Shape Text using the shapes collection object
function getSelectedShapeText() {

    Visio.run(function (ctx) {  
    var page = ctx.document.getActivePage();
     var shapes = page.shapes;
       shapes.load();
           return ctx.sync().then(function () {
          textArea.value = "Please select a Shape in the Diagram";
          for(var i=0; i<shapes.items.length;i++)
      {
         var shape = shapes.items[i];
                if ( shape.select == true)
            {
             textArea.value = shape.text;
                 return;
                }
      }
   });
     }).catch(function(error) {
  textArea.value = "Error: ";
  if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
   textArea.value += "Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo);
  }
    });
}
</script>
```

the Issue is Error i coming on click of selected shape Text Button.

Any help would greatly appreciated.Let me know if any query's in case you have not understood my question.

Answer (score 0):

Which URL do you enter? It is supposed to look like this:

..../_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7BXXX-XXX-XX%7D&file=Drawing4.vsdx&action=embedView

Means, you open Visio diagram in SharePoint, copy URL from the address bar and paste it into that field (replace XXXX with your value). If it does not work, replace "default" at the end with "embedView".